# Trying to Validate Math Expression Recursively - What's wrong with this code?

Tags: c++, function, recursion, boolean

Valid Expression = *single digit*

AND

Valid Expression = ( *Valid Expression* + *Valid Expression* )

Which means that the boolean function that I'm trying to create will only accept as valid, expressions of the following type:

```
5
(5+3)
(6+(3+2))
((7+1)+(5+1))
............... etc.
```

I want my function's parameters to stay as they are (istringstream& is) and I want to use a get(ch) in my function.

I also want to do it recursively. However, I'm doing something wrong and it only validates expressions of type : *single digit*

Where's the problem in my recursion? And I know it's not even a proper recursion, I'm sure a proper recursion could do the job even in fewer lines and with no nested ifs..

Thank you for any helpful suggestions!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

bool isvalid(istringstream& is)
{
    char ch;
    is.get(ch);
    if(ch-'0'>=0 || ch-'0'<=9) return true;
    if(ch=='(' && isvalid(is))
    {   
        is.get(ch);
        if(ch=='+' && isvalid(is))
        {
            is.get(ch);
            if(ch==')') return true;
        }
     }
     return false; 
}
bool empty(istringstream& is)
{
    char ch;
    is.get(ch);
    return is.fail(); 
}

int main() 
{    
    string s;    
    while(getline(cin,s))    
    {   
        istringstream is(s);
        cout<<(isvalid(is) && empty(is) ? "Expression OK" : "Not OK")<<endl;    
    } 
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(ch-'0'>=0 || ch-'0'<=9) return true;
```

This needs to be an && expression, doesn't it?

Comment: oops :) but still.. it's not working, what that mistake was doing was that it would evaluate to true even if the numbers where >9 .. problem must be elsewhere..

Comment: problem solved, I had 3 bugs I believe : the one mentioned in this post, the other was a get(ch) I had omitted in a nested if and the other was an unnecessary call to the function after an if(")"..) Thanks to everyone who helped! :)

Answer (score 0):

Think about the string `()`. That will look like this:

isvalid("()"):  ch = '(' is not in 0-9, so it goes to the next line
                ch == '(', so it evaluates isValid(is).

second level: isvalid(")"): ch = ')', again, not 0-9, so it goes to the next line
                  ch != '(', so it shortcircuits the evaluation of the boolean expression and returns false

back to the first level: isvalid(is) failed, so we skip the if block and return false

Comment: you're right, and () is an invalid expression so there's nothing wrong with that, the problem is that it evaluates to false even expressions of the type (5+3) or (6+(4+3)) which are valid..

Comment: ...good point. So try (5+3). in the second level, ch = '5' and we return true, go back up, grab the next character so we're in the if block with ch = '+', we call is valid again and it's three so we keep going, and get the next char so we have ")" and should be returning true. So I'm stumped. Try outputting the value of "ch" at each step -- that will help get a mental picture of what's happening if you dont have a debugger to step through with.

Answer (score 0):

In `if(ch==')' && isvalid(is)) return true;`

I don't think you need the `&& isvalid(is)` part. It does not follow your grammar

Comment: I deleted it but it's still not doing the job

Comment: It has been long since I programmed in C++, so I don't remember the exact semantics of the stream methods. Are you sure your empty function is not the one causing the problem? (maybe an end-of-line, or end-of-string character?)

Comment: That's what I was wondering right now. Am I omitting (in my isvalid function) the case where ch is the return character (ch=='\n')? Is that the problem? But if that was the case it wouldn't work even for single digit expressions, but it does work for that kind..

Comment: I think your isvalid function should be OK. the problem may be in your empty(). Could you omit checking for empty, for a while, just to check is isvalid() works OK?

Comment: check the answer just posted by yeahbro: that's also a good catch

Comment: if you omit the empty() it will evaluate to true only if your expression starts with a valid expression. First make sure of that, then, when that is fixed, deal with the rest. Even better: print out the remainder of the stream, to see how much was recognized by your code

Comment: nope.. I tried any kind of input ("&", ")6+%"...etc.).. always true without the empty() function...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8198/discussion-between-eduardo-and-user1073400)

Answer (score 0):

The inner if(ch==')' && ...) will always be false (since ch=='+' if you get to that if) -- there's a get(ch) missing.

Comment: absolutely right, I had omitted a "get(ch)" in that inner if, still not working though...